How to explicitly construct flat polynomial approximation to the exponential function?
I have been reading the paper “Learning quantum Hamiltonians at any temperature in polynomial time”. This paper seems to be very interesting and has appeared in Quanta Magazine 2024 for "2024's Biggest Breakthroughs in Computer Science" review. As an electrical engineer, I am only interested in the "new flat polynomial approximation to the exponential function" presented by this paper. Particularly, this properties make it desirable for making VLSI hardware such as decoder for convolutional code.

However, the paper does not provide any explicit examples or look up table on how to construct these wonderful approximations. The only thing it gives is just some theorem that is very difficult to understand for us engineer.

Therefore, out of my curiosity (as an engineer) my question is "How to explicitly construct flat polynomial approximation to the exponential function ?"
Could anyone with experience or insights in this area kindly clarify this matter for me ?

The definition $4.2 - 4.4$ sections show how to construct these $2$ objects.   Specifically definition $4.4$ shows $p_{k,ℓ}(x)$ as the product of $k$ progressively longer truncated Taylor series of $e^x$.  Specifically, we have: $$p_{k,ℓ}(x) = \prod_{n=1}^{k} s_{(2^nℓ)}(x/k)$$  where:
$$s_ℓ(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{ℓ} \frac{x^{k}}{k!}$$ In practice this seems rather tedious to compute (we multiply $k$ long Taylor truncation polynomials, our $s$ terms, to get our $p$ terms, which are the "flat approximations"), so maybe there could be a simpler way to get them. I don't know.

I am sorry but would you kindly provide some example up to 3 terms or at least some matlab / python code to illustrate the ideas. These symbolic presentation is too difficult to understand
